# Table for magnetic moments for all elements in periodic table?

Tags: magnetism

I'm trying to look for a table for magnetic moments for all elements of the periodic table for my research project in computational chemistry, can anyone direct me to a suitable one?

Comment: Magnetic moment is not a property of elements.

Answer (score 1):

Unpaired electrons will give rise to a magnetic moment equal to the 'spin only' value $\mu_s=g\sqrt{S(S+1)}$ in units of Bohr Magnetons, $e\hbar/2m_e$, for example H atoms  with $S=1/2$. $g$ is the magnetogyric ratio $\approx 2$.

There may also be an orbital contribution (from orbital angular momentum) depending on what levels are filled then the equation becomes $\mu_{s+L}=\sqrt{4S(S+1)+L(L+1)}$ where $L$ is the orbital angular quantum number, e.g. $V^{3+},\,S=1,\,L=3$ gives $\mu_{s+L}=4.47$.

(Many transition metal complexes have values differing from this formula  because of bonding between metal and ligand restricts the orbital angular momentum. You will need to consult texts on Ligand Field Theory and come to grips with the Van Vleck equation to understand this topic in more detail.)